# unable to copy and paste in gitk - macosx

Tags: git, macos, gitk

does anyone know how to copy and paste in gitk with macosx?

Its the lower left pane i am unable to select,highlight and copy the text/changes there?

Thanks.

Comment: I am able to use the mouse to select and ⌘C/⌘V to copy and paste it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to copy from gitk by pressing: `fn-⌘-C`